# Sound id for lightning bolt

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to play the sound of a lightning bolt, but nobody seems to have asked this question before. if the version changes anything, the version im in is 1.12.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thunder sound is `entity.lightning_bolt.thunder`.

The impact sound is `entity.lightning_bolt.impact`.

<sup>[Source](https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/sound_list_pc.php)</sup>